# c# count a specific word happen times in a txt file

Tags: c#, console

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader oReader;
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\cmd.txt"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IMAGE");
            string cSearforSomething = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
            oReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\cmd.txt");
            string cColl = oReader.ReadToEnd();
            string cCriteria = @"\b" + cSearforSomething + @"\b";
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex oRegex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(cCriteria, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);



            int count = oRegex.Matches(cColl).Count;
            Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I cannot calculate the string "IMAGE" happen times in my file? Is my code wrong?

Comment: Don't use `File.Exists()`. This is a case where you should just handle the exception if opening the file fails.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn still cannot calculate the happen times happen in mytxt file.

Comment: You can use Linq here. cCol1.Count(x => x == cSearchForSomething)

Comment: @RohitGarg The OP is not looking to count single characters.

Comment: Well, what *does* the code do? If it is "nothing", then it might be time to heed Joel's comment - could it be the Exists check is not even passing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
public static void Main()
{
    var str = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\cmd.txt");
    var searchTerm = "IMAGE";

    var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"\b" + searchTerm + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    Console.WriteLine(matches.Count);
    Console.ReadLine();            
}
```

Comment: *Why* should the OP try it? What potentially makes it 'work'? It looks much as the original, slightly tidied up.

Comment: @user2864740 I don't know what makes OP's code doesn't work. It maybe `File.Exists` check or something. I rewrite OP's code without `File.Exists` check, test it on my side to ensure it's working and let OP try and then waiting for OP's feedback about it, maybe some exception arise or something. But OP accept it, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx the "\b" matches a backspace. That might explain why you aren't matching the regular expression.

Comment: "In a *character class*, [\b] matches a backspace, \u0008." - Outside of a character class \b matches a word boundary. "The [\b outside of a character class] match must occur on a boundary between a \w (alphanumeric) and a \W (nonalphanumeric) character."

Answer (score 0):

using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string cColl = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\some.txt");
        //string cColl = "This is similar, similar, similar, similar, similar, similar";
        Console.WriteLine(cColl);

        string cCriteria = @"\b" + "similar" + @"\b";
        Regex oRegex = new Regex(cCriteria, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        int count = oRegex.Matches(cColl).Count;
        Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }




}
```

}